# How do you prove probabilities are closed under multiplication with dependent types?

Tags: proof, dependent-type, idris

I'm working a bit with Idris and I've written a type for probabilities - `Float`s between `0.0` and `1.0`:

```
data Probability : Type where
    MkProbability : (x : Float) -> ((x >= 0.0) && (x <= 1.0) = True) -> Probability
```

I want to be able to multiply them:

```
multProbability : Probability -> Probability -> Probability
multProbability (MkProbability p1 proof1) (MkProbability p2 proof2) =
    MkProbability (p1 * p2) ???
```

How can I prove that `p1 * p2` will always be a probability?

Comment: What is the theory of `Float`s in Idris? For e.g. rationals represented as `Int :/ Nat` (so e.g. 0.5 would be represented as `1 :/ 1` since we assume an implicit `Suc` in the denominator to avoid zeroes), you would define ordering such that `0 <= p :/ q <= 1` is equivalent to `0 <= p <= Suc q`, then all you have to prove is `0 <= p1 <= Suc q1 -> 0 <= p2 <= Suc q2 -> 0 <= (p1 * p2) <= (Suc q1 * Suc q2)` which is easy enough to do via the monotonicity of multiplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd remove floating-point numbers from the picture. You're almost always going to have problems with primitives, but especially when dealing with the weird details of the IEEE 754 type.

Instead, I'd represent probabilities using a ratio type:

```
record Probability : Type where
  MkProbability : (numerator : Nat) ->
                  (denominator : Nat) ->
                  LTE numerator (S denominator) ->
                  Probability
```

`LTE` is a type where values only exist when the first `Nat` is less than or equal to the second `Nat`. The `(S denominator)` is to ensure we don't have a denominator of zero. This means `MkProbability 2 1 (LTESucc LTEZero)` is valid and represents a probability `1.0`, looks weird but ensures validity.

We can then get a `Float` out of the type:

```
toFloat : Probability -> Float
toFloat (MkProbability n d _) =
  fromInteger (toIntegerNat n) / fromInteger (toIntegerNat (S d))
```

Another benefit is that this is arbitrary precision until we convert to a `Float`.

A problem is that you're probably going to have to build large `LTE` values. Using `isLTE` for runtime values will probably help here!